# Non-strict Evaluation of Option[Boolean]

Tags: scala

Given a `List[Foo]`, I apply a function `f`.

`def f(foo: Foo): Option[Boolean]`

I wrote this function body to see if **any** Foo evaluates to `Some(true)`.

```
val optFalse: Option[Boolean] = Some(false)
val foos: List[Foo] = ... 

foos.foldLeft(optFalse){ 
     (acc: Option[Boolean], elem: Foo) => {
        val isMatch: Option[Boolean] = f(elem)
        optionOr(acc)(match) // takes 2 Option[Boolean] and `or`'s them.
     }
}
```

However, the `f` method could be an expensive operation. I'd prefer to "short-circuit":

```
foos.foldLeft(optFalse){ 
     (acc: Option[Boolean], elem: Foo) => {
        if( isTrueOption(acc) ) acc
        else {
         val isMatch: Option[Boolean] = f(elem)
         isMatch
        }        
     }
}
```

Is there a **non-strict** way to fold over the entire `List[Foo]`, but stop evaluation once one of the `Option[Boolean]` equals `Some(true)` **without** my changed code? Perhaps using the `=>` operator?

If so, I'm thinking that there's a "space" cost, but I'm not entirely understanding it. Please include that topic as well in your answer (if there is one).

Comment: Do you want to use `foldLeft` no matter what? The problem can be easily solved using explicit recursion.

Comment: Good point. For this question, I'm interested in foldLeft in particular due to non-strictness

Comment: foldLeft will always loop over the whole list unless an exception is thrown... an Exception, try throwing a custom exception and handle it. It is disgusting but this is the only way I could think of. :)

Comment: @Peter - I understand that the whole list will be traversed. However, I'd like to know if the **evaluation** of the `fold`'ed list can be performed non-strictly. PS - suggesting using an Exception, even if with a `:)`, in a `foldLeft` shouldn't be even mentioned in jest!

Comment: Actually, I can evaluate it non-strictly, I believe, by making `optionOr` evaluate its arguments **non-strictly**.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what role `Option` is playing in your code. If you just want to find out whether there's any value for which `f` returns `Some(true)`, that sounds like a good use case for `exists`, which is short-circuit:

```
foos.exists{x => Some(true) == f(x)}
```

If you need to know whether any `f` returns `None`, then clearly you'll need to evaluate the whole list (at least in the case where they're actually all `Some`, which is presumably the interesting case).

If it has to be a `fold`, then `fold` is strict (it would be possible to write a non-strict fold, but that wouldn't be the standard `fold`). You could use @Peter's solution in a more structured way by using `breakable`.

Comment: This an interesting comment: `If you need to know whether any f returns None, then clearly you'll need to evaluate the whole list`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
foos.reduce { 
     case (Some(true), _)=> Some(true)
     case (_, x) => f(x)
}
```